# Fill two-dimensional array with random letters

Tags: excel, vba

I'd like to fill a two-dimensional array in Excel (let's say A1:J20) with random letters. How can I do this using programming (or even without programming, if possible)?

Answer (score 1):

A formula that returns a random lowercase letter between a and z would be:

```
=CHAR(97+RANDBETWEEN(0,25))
```

**How It Works**

The `=char()` formula returns the letter for the number code.

- Note that 97 is for lowercase a, and 65 is for uppercase A.

The `RANDBETWEEN` function returns a random number between 0 and 25. we'll start with the letter a, and then add this random number to it to get the final result.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy in formulas.

First, put this formula into a cell somewhere: `=CODE("A")` - You should see the number 65. Then, try `=CODE("Z")` - this will show 90.

You now have the numeric codes for letters A and Z

What you actually want to do is calculate random numbers between 65 and 90, and then translate these numbers back into characters.

So here's the formula, for any cell, which wil obtain a random whole number between 65 and 90:  `=TRUNC(65 + (RAND() * (91 - 65)))` - note the integer arithmetic I'm using has a truncation, so I'm adding 1 to the upper boundary...

Finally, feed the results into a function, `CHAR()` that returns a character from its ACSII code:

`=CHAR(TRUNC(65 + (RAND() * (91 - 65))))`

That should work...